# get pixel colours from TIFFbuf

Tags: delphi, tiff, libtiff

I need to get color info from tiff file, so i read it tile by tile with help of LibTiffDelphi lib. Tiff is monochrome, packed in PackBits.

I read every tile to a buff and after that I need to get % of black and white in each tilem broblem is I dont know how to get this info from buf.

```
procedure readTiff (OpenTiff : PTIFF);
var
  buf :^char;
  tileByteCounts : array of Integer;
  ...
begin
  bufsize:= TIFFStripSize(OpenTiff);
  buf:=_TIFFmalloc(bufsize);

 for s:= 0 to  tileCount  do
            begin
               if (Tilebytecounts[s]< bufsize) then       
                begin
                buf := _TIFFrealloc(buf, Tilebytecounts[s]);
                  if (buf)=nil then
                    begin
                Exit;
                bufsize:= Tilebytecounts[s];
                    end;
                  rc := (TIFFReadRawTile(OpenTiff, s, buf, Tilebytecounts[s]));
                  if rc < 0 then
                     begin
                       _TIFFfree(buf);
                        Exit;
                     end;
                end;
             end;
          _TIFFfree(buf);

    TIFFClose(OpenTiff);
```

Or, as a case, how to save this buf to bitmap file?

Comment: You need to get the PhotometricInterpretation tag to know if black is 0 or 1 and then the BitsPerSample tag to know how to interpret the bytes, then you can add up the black and white pixels.